# Probability of drawing winning combination of Magic Card at first turn

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we are playing a simple card game (e.g. like Magic). In this game, each player has a card deck which contains 50 cards (with no duplicate cards). At the start of this game, both players shuffle their decks. Then the player going first draws five cards, and the player going second draws six cards. After this, the game starts, and players alternate turns.

Suppose there is a special combination of five cards, and if you have those five cards in your hand you instantly win the game.

What is the probability that the second player will draw this combination on their first turn and win the game immediately?

Comment: Did you try something? How would you approach this?

Comment: I guessed but not sure: total evens are 50 choose 6 (denominator), and 5 choose 5 multiplied with 45 choose 1 (nominator).

Comment: Who wins if both players draw the winning combination? They have both a deck, right?

Comment: Each person will have their own deck, like Magic Game

Comment: @NguyenAn You overlooked that the first player does not win, so you need to enforce that as well.

Comment: Thank you Shubham

Answer (score 1):

Since the first person does not win, he must not have drawn the $5$ winning cards in the first draw. The probability of this happening is $1$ minus the probability of him drawing those $5$ cards in the first draw i.e.$$1-\frac{\binom55}{\binom{50}5}$$The second person picks the $5$ winning cards and $1$ additional card, so this probability is$$\frac{\binom{45}1\cdot\binom55}{\binom{50}6}$$The required probability is the product of the above two terms, assuming the events are independent.